HTML5 Canvas - Rotate Canvas Using Easing Function
Problem:
Easing rotation through HTML5 canvas animation, stopping at the desired angle (or degree of rotation) at the end of the animation. Essentially, stretching this easing animation (smoothly) over the course of the entire animation's time-span; without being tied to an indeterministic fps value.
Takeaways:
The _rotate function operates properly for jumping to specific degree values in a single call.
The problem occurs when you want to smoothly _progress through this rotation, from 0 to _desiredAngle.
Attempting to obtain each semi-degree by simply multiplying _desiredAngle and the current _progress (0 - 1), of the animation, doesn't produce the right semi-degrees required for a smooth transition. This is my thinking ATM, and I may be looking at this incorrectly.
Having an _fpsEstimate value does narrow the window on that 90 degree translation. The caveat here is that this animation is now tied to that magic number, and depending on the load takin (for multiple animations) this value will change. To retain accuracy while under load, I'm attempting to find a more exacting method of achieving a similar result; without having to divide by step counters, or fps in flux.
Example - Canvas


let _canvas       = document.querySelector ( 'canvas' );

let _context      = _canvas.getContext ( '2d' );

let _coordinates  = { x: 100, y: 100 }

let _desiredAngle = 90;

let _time         = 3000;

let _fpsEstimate  = 65;

////    FUNCTIONS    ///////////////////////////////////////

/**
 * Timing function for easeInSine
 * @param       {number} timeFraction                       Timing fraction
 * @return      {number}                                    Progress
 */
function _timingFunction ( timeFraction )
{
    return 1 - Math.cos ( ( timeFraction * Math.PI ) / 2 );
}

/**
 * Rotate canvas
 * @param       {number} degree                             Degree to rotate
 * @param       {Object} coordinates                        X & Y coordinates
 */
function _rotate ( degree, coordinates )
{
    let [ _x, _y ] = [ coordinates.x, coordinates.y ];


    _context.save ( );

    _context.translate ( _x, _y );

    _context.rotate ( degree * Math.PI / 180 );

    _context.translate ( -_x, -_y );
}

/**
 * Animate object
 */
function _animate ( )
{
    let _start = performance.now ( );

    let _width  = 50;
        
    let _height = 50;


    requestAnimationFrame (

        function animate ( time )
        {
            _context.clearRect ( 0, 0, 500, 500 );


            let _timeFraction =  ( time - _start ) / _time;         // timeFraction goes from 0 to 1

            let _progress     = _timingFunction ( _timeFraction );  // calculate the current animation state

            let _rotateAmount = _progress * _desiredAngle / _fpsEstimate;          // calculate distance between current progress & desire angle
            
            
            _rotate ( _rotateAmount, _coordinates );

        
            _context.strokeRect ( _coordinates.x - ( _width / 2 ), _coordinates.y - ( _height / 2 ), _width, _height );


            ( _timeFraction < 1 )

                ? requestAnimationFrame ( animate )

                : console.log ( 'complete !' );
        }
    );
}

////    INIT    ////////////////////////////////////////////

_animate ( );
<canvas width='500' height='500'></canvas>



Example - CSS
This can be accomplished via CSS easily. However, I am looking for the same solution via in canvas.


.rotate   { animation: rotation 2s;            }
.easing   { animation-timing-function: easeIn; }
.infinite { animation-iteration-count: 1;      }

@keyframes rotation 
{
  from { transform: rotate(0deg);  }
  to   { transform: rotate(90deg); }
}
<img src="https://pngimg.com/uploads/square/square_PNG35.png" class="rotate linear infinite" width="75" height="75" />




I think the problem is deeper then you thought... I mean... Is it something that is spinning and then you want some function to make it stop spinning smoothly over a defined timer and reach your desired angle? Your function is doing the opposite... It start the spinning, accelerates it and then stop when the timer crashes (it's not ending but it just stops repeating when the time calculation fails _timeFraction > 1). Note that HTML/Javascript fps is locked at 60fps. This means your _animate() should run 60 times per second.

@user2804429 Tying this animation to 60 fps, or in this case 65 fps does narrow the window on that 90 degree translation. The caveat here is that this animation is now tied to that magic number, and depending on the load takin (for multiple animations) this value will change. To retain accuracy while under load, I'm attempting to find a more exacting method of achieving a similar result; without having to divide by an fps value that's in flux.

This code is difficult to read. Please format with Prettier and avoid whitespace between every line.

Solution
It appears as though I have found a solution, from this 8 year old post Precise rotation around world axis using Tween.
The key seems simple... track the accumulated _rotation of each semi rotation (_rotate), tracking the distance between each angle; i.e. 0 - _angle.
Note: This _rotation value should also be zeroed out at the beginning of each animation.
Then, calculate how much you need to _rotate the animation, by multiplying _progress by the desired _angle subtracted by the present _rotation distance.
let _rotate = _progress * ( _angle - _rotation );

Working Solution


let _canvas       = document.querySelector ( 'canvas' );

let _context      = _canvas.getContext ( '2d' );

let _coordinates  = { x: 100, y: 100 }

let _angle        = 90;

let _time         = 2000;

let _rotation     = undefined;          // tracks n rotation(s) through each cycle

////    FUNCTIONS    ///////////////////////////////////////

/**
 * Timing function for easeInSine
 * @param       {number} timeFraction                       Timing fraction
 * @return      {number}                                    Progress
 */
function _timingFunction ( timeFraction )
{
    return 1 - Math.cos ( ( timeFraction * Math.PI ) / 2 );
}

/**
 * Rotate canvas
 * @param       {number} degree                             Degree to rotate
 * @param       {Object} coordinates                        X & Y coordinates
 */
function _rotateCanvas ( degree, coordinates )
{
    let [ _x, _y ] = [ coordinates.x, coordinates.y ];


    _context.save ( );

    _context.translate ( _x, _y );

    _context.rotate ( degree * Math.PI / 180 );

    _context.translate ( -_x, -_y );
}

/**
 * Animate object
 */
function _animate ( )
{
    let _start = performance.now ( );

    let _width  = 50;
        
    let _height = 50;

        _rotation = 0;
    
    
    requestAnimationFrame (

        function animate ( time )
        {
            _context.clearRect ( 0, 0, 500, 500 );


            let _timeFraction =  ( time - _start ) / _time;         // timeFraction goes from 0 to 1

            let _progress     = _timingFunction ( _timeFraction );  // calculate the current animation state

            let _rotate       = _progress * ( _angle - _rotation ); // calculate distance between current progress & desire angle
            
            
            _rotateCanvas ( _rotate, _coordinates );

            
            _rotation += _rotate;       // <== sum rotational distance through each cycle
            
        
            _context.strokeRect ( _coordinates.x - ( _width / 2 ), _coordinates.y - ( _height / 2 ), _width, _height );


            ( _timeFraction < 1 )

                ? requestAnimationFrame ( animate )

                : console.log ( 'complete !' );
        }
    );
}

////    INIT    ////////////////////////////////////////////

_animate ( );
<canvas width='500' height='500'></canvas>



Final Thoughts
This solution appears to maintain the easing gradient(s) when using different easing formulas, while accurately tying each animation's length (in _time); creating a smooth transition, while scaling each transition type with each animation loop.
CSS Comparison


.rotate   { animation: rotation 2s;            }
.easing   { animation-timing-function: easeIn; }
.infinite { animation-iteration-count: 1;      }

@keyframes rotation 
{
  from { transform: rotate(0deg);  }
  to   { transform: rotate(90deg); }
}
<img src="https://pngimg.com/uploads/square/square_PNG35.png" class="rotate linear infinite" width="75" height="75" />



